# Python3, can't import numpy

Tags: python, numpy, data-science

***I am unable to import numpy.
Tried to uninstall and reinstall numpy by using pip and pip3.
Checked PATH.
I am using Python3 on Windows 10.***

*Below is the whole error:*

Python 3.7.1 (v3.7.1:260ec2c36a, Oct 20 2018, 14:57:15) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import numpy
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\core__init__.py", line 40, in 
> > >           from . import multiarray
> > >         File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.py", line 13, in 
> > >           from . import overrides
> > >         File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py", line 6, in 
> > >           from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
> > >       ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy__init__.py", line 142, in 
    from . import core
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\core__init__.py", line 71, in 
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError:

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
Here is how to proceed:
- If you're working with a numpy git repository, try `git clean -xdf`
  (removes all files not under version control) and rebuild numpy.
- If you are simply trying to use the numpy version that you have installed:
  your installation is broken - please reinstall numpy.
- If you have already reinstalled and that did not fix the problem, then:
  1. Check that you are using the Python you expect (you're using C:\Python37\python.exe),
     and that you have no directories in your PATH or PYTHONPATH that can
     interfere with the Python and numpy versions you're trying to use.
  2. If (1) looks fine, you can open a new issue at
     https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues.  Please include details on:
     - how you installed Python
     - how you installed numpy
     - your operating system
     - whether or not you have multiple versions of Python installed
     - if you built from source, your compiler versions and ideally a build log

```
 Note: this error has many possible causes, so please don't comment on
 an existing issue about this - open a new one instead.
```

Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: Well, did you follow the suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a more seamless experience on windows, try using PyCharm or Anaconda which will automatically install numpy/scipy for you, rather than the standard python interpreter.